# Force wpf control update from View Model

Tags: wpf, mvvm, user-controls, custom-controls

I currently develop a WPF control which is simply canvas with some additional properties like grid lines, children drag and drop etc.

I need a mechanism to call some of my canvas functional from view model binded to view that contains my canvas.
For example, view can contain my canvas and a button "Show grid". When user clicks the button canvas should paint grid on itself.

The problem is to do this according to MVVM pattern without direct reference to canvas in view's view model.
What is the best practice to do this?

Comment: I don't have time to write an answer look at how to use RoutedCommand
Hook it up in your control and raise it from your ViewModel.

Answer (score 0):

UI related stuff can be still written in view behind cs file. It does not mean that you violated MVVM. If view models are for business logic, view behind is for view logic. To achieve more encapsulation and re-usability, you can use [Behaviors](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff725476(v=expression.40).aspx).

You can write a behavior which do all painting logic and attach it to the button. Even you can add dependency properties to your behavior to have more control on it.

Comment: Yes, all specific UI related logic is in control codebehind (I simply inherit from Canvas). There is a command binded to my button. The command handler ShowGrid() is in view model. What should I write in it to make grid lines apper in canvas?

Comment: Add a behavior with a Dependency Property of type Boolean, "ShowGridLines". Do your grid lines rendering logic in callback of the Property in Behavior.

Comment: If I understand you corrrectly, I need to create a custom behavior attached to button which will bind to boolean property that I can change from my VM. There is a problem with this solution: I want all rendering logic to be in canvas codebehind. There are many similar tasks I wand to accomplish with my canvas, and I don't want to atomize rendering logic among dozens of behaviors